# What exactly is automated integration testing and how do you do it?

Tags: testing

What i understand by integration testing, is just executing the final program by hand and making sure it works as it should. I've been using automated unit testing for a while. But what exactly is automated integration testing?

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty much just tests that combine different units and a perfect extension of unit testing. Although your tests can pass individually, they can easily fail when combining them.

You can also use frameworks that tests your UI automatically and reads the input, so you dont have to test it every time.